# Spring MVC form - add success message and clear form

Tags: java, jquery, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC form which upon POST handles the errors and displays them correctly on the form(Shows the errors on the same page and does not clear the data from the form). I also want to add a success message on the form upon successful transaction and also clear the form content.

I have no clue on how to handle the success message. I tried passing it as an error to the form, but this is displayed in red color which is the color i used for error. I am unable to change the color to green for this message.

```
         model.addAttribute("serverError", "Transaction inserted Successfully !"); 
     return "checkinout";
```

Here is my code-

.css

```
.plErroMessage{margin-left:185px;color:white;background-color:red;width:165px;padding: 4px;}
```

checkinout.jsp

```
<div class="devices">
    <form:form method="post" id="assetForm" modelAttribute="inOutTransaction" action="/DeviceManager/assets">
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="plErroMessage" element="div" />
        <br>
        <c:if test="${not empty serverError}">
            <div id="serverError" class="plErroMessage">${serverError}</div>
        </c:if>
        <form:hidden path="actionId"/>
        <div>
            <div class="plLabelSearch">User Id:</div> 
            <div class="plinput"><form:input path="userId" size="29"/></div>
        </div>    <!-- More Code follows -->
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/assets", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
 public String checkInOut(@ModelAttribute("inOutTransaction") @Validated InOutTransaction inOutTransaction, BindingResult result, Model model, Locale locale) {
     try {
         if(result.hasErrors()){
             return "checkinout";
         }
         InOutTransactionDO inOutTransactionDO = new InOutTransactionDO();
/*CODE*/
         if(employeeInfoDO == null){
             model.addAttribute("serverError", "User "+ inOutTransaction.getUserId()+" does not exist !"); 
             return "checkinout";
         }
/*CODE*/
         if(deviceMasterDO == null){
             model.addAttribute("serverError", "Device Id "+ inOutTransaction.getAssetTagNumber()+" not found !"); 
             return "checkinout";           
         }
         inOutTransactionService.saveTransaction(inOutTransactionDO);
         model.addAttribute("serverError", "Transaction inserted Successfully !"); 
         return "checkinout";
          } catch (Exception e) {   
            model.addAttribute("serverError", e.toString()); 
            return "checkinout";  
          }
}
```

Comment: If I decide to send the success message as an error, How can change the css for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better solutions but I came up with this so far in the past.

1) Add HttpServletRequest request in parameters

```
@RequestMapping(value="/assets", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public String checkInOut(@ModelAttribute("inOutTransaction") @Validated InOutTransaction inOutTransaction, 
BindingResult result, Model model, Locale locale, HttpServletRequest request) {
 try {
     if(result.hasErrors()){
         return "checkinout";
     }
     InOutTransactionDO inOutTransactionDO = new InOutTransactionDO();
/*CODE*/
     if(employeeInfoDO == null){
         model.addAttribute("serverError", "User "+ inOutTransaction.getUserId()+" does not exist !"); 
         return "checkinout";
     }
/*CODE*/
     if(deviceMasterDO == null){
         model.addAttribute("serverError", "Device Id "+ inOutTransaction.getAssetTagNumber()+" not found !"); 
         return "checkinout";           
     }
     inOutTransactionService.saveTransaction(inOutTransactionDO);
     request.getSession().setAttribute("successMessage", "Transaction inserted Successfully !"); 
     return "checkinout";
      } catch (Exception e) {   
        model.addAttribute("serverError", e.toString()); 
        return "checkinout";  
      }
}
```

2) Add the success message to jsp and clear the session variable at end of jsp

```
<div class="devices">
<form:form method="post" id="assetForm" modelAttribute="inOutTransaction" action="/DeviceManager/assets">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="plErroMessage" element="div" />
   <c:if test="${not empty successMessage}">
        <div id="serverError" class="successMessage">${successMessage}</div>
    </c:if>        
     <br>
    <c:if test="${not empty serverError}">
        <div id="serverError" class="plErroMessage">${serverError}</div>
    </c:if>
    <form:hidden path="actionId"/>
    <div>
        <div class="plLabelSearch">User Id:</div> 
        <div class="plinput"><form:input path="userId" size="29"/></div>
    </div>

 <c:remove var="successMessage" scope="session" />
```

3) Create new css for the success message

4) To clear the form upon success, either you redirect the page or send the new blank object to the view.

The reason I set the success message in httpSession instead of model is because, by default spring appends the model attributes on url upon redirect. if you don't want to redirect and want to send the blank object then, adding to model.addAttribute also fine.

Comment: I added the success message to model.addAttribute and displayed it in the form with my required css format.